# Regular Pumping Lemma

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

> $$\begin{align*}
> L&=\left\{b^5w:w\in\{a,b\}^*,\big(2n_a(w)+5n_b(w)\big)\bmod 3=0\right\}\\
> L&=\left\{(ab)^na^k:n>k,k\ge 0\right\}
> \end{align*}$$

Determine if each language is regular or not-regular. The former justied by providing a minimal DFA which accepts the said language and the latter by using the Pumping Lemma for Regular Expressions. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried? As a rule of thumb, DFA cannot count natural numbers (since they are infinite many of them and the automata is finite), so that the second language is not regular. The first one, on the other hand, only count modulo 3, which is finite, so it is going to be regular.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For the first question, show that the expression $2n_a(w)+5n_b(w)$ increases by $2$ modulo $3$ for each letter of $w$. Thus, it will cycle repeatedly through the numbers $0,2,1$ in that order. Three states will suffice to take care of that, and taking care of the initial $b^5$ is very straightforward.

For the second question, if $p$ is the pumping length, consider the word $(ab)^pa^{p-1}$. You’ll have to consider more than one case, and you’ll want to remember that you can pump down as well as up.